# Filtering column with aggregated function with itself to show max records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am having a hard time trying to figure out the best way to filter records against itself using the MAX function.

My desired results are to have my IDs in one column and then the max records from the group by on the next column.

```
ID       Max_id  group_id
3000  3004     6
3001  3004      6  
3002  3004      6
3003  3004      6
4000  4004      20
4001   4004      20
4000   4001      42
```

Here is my table structure and sampling data. I can use a min and max function and group by group_id but cannot access the middle ID's when doing this. When I attempt to use just the ID without the min() I get constraint errors.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40ef34/1

Comment: you may need to add expected ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` here.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40ef34/5)

```
SELECT
  g.id, m.maxid,g.group_id
FROM
  groups g
 cross join (select group_id, max(id) as maxid from groups group by group_id) m 
 where m.group_id = g.group_id and g.id <> m.maxid
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Can you maybe break down the thought process of your query? I understand this jist of it. But I would like to know what was your thought process!